# Is there a way to view the SourceLink data in a PDB file in order to validate that SourceLink is working?

Tags: debugging, debug-symbols, sourcelink

I created a targets file to enable SourceLink.  When running the build, I was able to validate that the `source_link.json` files were being generated.

However, when I try to check the PDB with `srctool.exe [PDB file path]`, it says the file is not source indexed.

Because SourceLink appears to be a newer process, I'm not sure if `srctool.exe` is compatible with it or not.

Is there any easy way to "break open" a PDB file and verify that the SourceLink information exists?

Comment: Please add more hashtags to let more relevant folks reach to your question. Some more general hashtags like the main framework, language or toolkit used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the free tool [dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to see the content of the PDB via `Tools`->`Show PDB content`:

[image]

When you scroll to the end, you see the SourceLink entry if it was added:

[image]